# Discrepancy between Google Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I'm getting different results for [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjbMf/) on Google Chrome (14.0.835.186) and Firefox (6.0.2).

Can anyone explain the discrepancy? What is the behaviour determined by the specifications?

***EDIT***: On Firefox I see `[0]`, `[0, 1]`, etc. On Chrome I see `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, etc.

I'm using Mac OS 10.6.8.

Comment: Looks like it has been reported as a bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35801

Comment: To get around it, you could do `var a = []; console.log(a.join(',')); a[0] = 1; console.log(a.join(','));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**See:**

- [Your example with console.log before the loop](http://jsfiddle.net/bjbMf/3/)
- [Your example using document.write](http://jsfiddle.net/bjbMf/6/)
- [Bizarre console.log behaviour in Chrome Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198912/bizarre-console-log-behaviour-in-chrome-developer-tools)

It's an odd behavior or the console, though I can't tell you why.

**Edit:**  Just to make sure it's clear, this is a 'bug' in the console only, there is no problem with the way the arrays are created in Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox is more technically correct in this case as it outputs the state of the object at each point in the loop whereas Chrome is apparently waiting until the end of the loop to output each console.log, but I'm not aware of a standards specification that covers the console host object.

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/LRGP2/ to show that this is only console.log that has this odd behavior.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I don't think you're correct here.  This is a peculiarity of console.log and doesn't happen to other functions placed there.  See this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/LRGP2/ with a different function in the loop and it works as expected.

Comment: Yeah, I spoke too fast. It's a `console.log` issue, which makes debugging more challenging. Edit your answer, and I'll upvote.

Comment: I added the jsFiddle to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are logging a **live object**.

Try the code below ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QyBcH/)) and see the difference:

```
var i, test = [];

for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
    test.push(i);
    console.log( test.toString() ); // notice .toString() addition
}
```

Btw, same and aggravated example can be seen in Opera Dragongfly - arrays are even clickable and expandable there.