# JavaScript console prints assigned value of variable before it has been assigned?

Tags: javascript

I'm deeply confused by the behaviour of either JavaScript, or the Chrome console. Can someone help me understand?

Basically I have the following JavaScript code, not nested inside any function or other scope:

```
var initial_array = [];

function initialiseArray() { 
   initial_array = [2, 9, 8, 6, 0, 2, 1];
} 

function copyToNewArray() {
    var copied_array = [];

    console.log("COPIED 1", copied_array);

    for (var i = 0; i < initial_array.length; i++) {
        var copy = initial_array[i];
        copied_array.push(copy);
    }

    console.log("COPIED 2", copied_array);
}

initialiseArray();
copyToNewArray();
```

I would expect `COPIED 1` to print `[]` - as the variable hasn't been assigned yet - but instead it prints `[2, 9, 8, 6, 0, 2, 1]` - ie the value after it has been assigned.

Why?

Incidentally, if you replace lines 8-11 with `initial_array = copied_array`, then `RESULTS 1` does indeed print as `[]`. Is it something to do with using `.push`?

Comment: Interesting. Does this seem to address the same issue? [link](http://zef.me/2843/javascript-the-scope-pitfall)

Comment: similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try debugging your issue in the Chrome script debugger. Put a breakpoint on the line:

```
for (var i = 0; i < initial_array.length; i++) {
```

and you will see the behaviour you desire.

The problem you are having is you are making the incorrect assumption that the Chrome debugger 'prints' the value immediately when in fact it does the `console.log` asynchronously. Since arrays are passed around by reference in the backend when it actually goes to print the value it is now the one you are seeing.

Comment: Good recommendation for Chrome script debugger, I was trying with Webstorm debugger without much success.

Comment: Good answer... LAME logger :(

Answer (score 3):

Since arrays are passed by reference, every change you make to it will change what is output in the console. It is partly the behavior of Chrome's console, partly JavaScript's.

If you want to print the result at the time of the call to `console.log`, you could output it as a string using `JSON.stringify`.

```
console.log("COPIED 1", JSON.stringify(copied_array));
```

**Important edit**

It seems I was mostly wrong. As *diEcho* pointed out in the question's comments, a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays) has a [better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4060176/104999). It seems to be solely Chrome behavior.

Comment: I also find this behaviour in firefox web developer console (the stock browser one, not firebug). So maybe it is not only a Chrome behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`console.log("COPIED 1", JSON.stringify(copied_array));`

Should be fine for debugging

---

it's a BUG you have mentioned, see below

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35801

also read similar questions

[Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

[Bizarre console.log behaviour in Chrome Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198912/bizarre-console-log-behaviour-in-chrome-developer-tools)

[Why does javascript object show different values in console in Chrome, Firefox, Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249136/why-does-javascript-object-show-different-values-in-console-in-chrome-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

It's the way arrays are displayed in the Chrome console, and that's by reference. If you want accurate results, convert to a string:

```
var initial_array = [];

function initialiseArray() { 
   initial_array = [2, 9, 8, 6, 0, 2, 1];
} 

function copyToNewArray() {
    var copied_array = [];

    console.log("COPIED 1", copied_array.toString());

    for (var i = 0; i < initial_array.length; i++) {
        var copy = initial_array[i];
        copied_array.push(copy);
    }

    console.log("COPIED 2", copied_array.toString());
}

initialiseArray();
copyToNewArray();
```

You can test this out pretty easily:

```
var x = [];
console.log(x), x.push(5), x; // outputs [5] and [5]
```

Comment: Still, you'd think it'd render/stringize/resolve the array reference at the proper point, otherwise `console.log`ging arrays would pretty much never work. Would Firefox succumb to this too, or is it more intelligent?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Not more intelligent, but rather converts everything to strings, so yes it should work. (FireBug, on the other hand... I'm not sure.)

Comment: I propose that that _is_ "more intelligent", because keeping the reference bound so late in this case clearly violates POLS. (FWIW, I meant to say Firebug)

Comment: To copy why not use `arr.slice()`?

Answer (score 1):

The console is actually asynchronous. Because you're logging a reference to an object, by the time the object is logged it has already changed.

You could clone the array before logging it to be certain that it doesn't get changed before it gets logged.

Answer (score 0):

```
var initial_array = [];
 function initialiseArray() { 
   initial_array = [2, 9, 8, 6, 0, 2, 1];
} 
function copyToNewArray() {
    var copied_array = [];
    console.log("COPIED 1", copied_array);
    alert(copied_array.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < initial_array.length; i++) {
        var copy = initial_array[i];
        copied_array.push(copy);
    }
    console.log("COPIED 2", copied_array);
}
initialiseArray();
copyToNewArray();
```

Adding the line `alert(copied_array.length);` will show correct results.

What happens is that the log is not synchronized with the javascript execution. When the log prints the values were already changed.

Answer (score 0):

that's because the `copied_array` is a reference, and console.log is executed asynchonously, so the content of the array is modifed before the first log prints it.

you may copy the array before printing

```
console.log([].concat(copied_array));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the console's functionality such as expanding objects in an array, I suggest using `.slice`, which makes a copy of the array which doesn't change when logging:

```
console.log("COPIED 1", copied_array.slice());
```

Comment: Nice but the JSON.stringify(copied_array) method seems better, i think.