# Weird behaviour when copying array with slice

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using Backbone.js, and in an overriden collection's `add` method I'm trying to copy an array with `slice`, the following way :

```
var modelsBefore = this.models.slice(0);
console.log('COPIED', modelsBefore, this.models);
```

But copy doesn't seem to work, here's what my (chromium) log shows :

```
COPIED [] [child]
```

Any idea what could cause this ?

EDIT :

Here's a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/hYDbw/5/

Comment: Why don't you store array in another variable ?

Comment: why you haven't set any argument in `slice()`

Comment: @Sarfraz: That's what he's trying to do...

Comment: @Sarfraz: If he just assigns it to another variable, both point to the same array.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Ah all right, true.

Comment: What is the output of `[1, 2, 3].slice()` in the Chrome Developer Tools console (use `Ctrl-Shift-J` on any page to bring up one)?

Comment: Arguments are **not** optional (even if your particular implementation happens to work otherwise, in its current version and configuration, on the current date and in your present location). Follow the documented API, not pure chance

Comment: like Lightness Races in Orbit say below they are not optional just because it still works. what if only standard is all of a sudden supported...

Comment: Ok thanks, but that's another topic ...

Comment: I think the problem here is actually one of `console.log`'s asynchronicity. Did you try with `alert`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : Well done, I've just found the answer also : http://jsfiddle.net/sebpiq/hYDbw/14/ console : I hate you. You can post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @sebpiq: Hopefully this is a lesson in posting an _actual_ testcase. What a waste of time this all was!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : if I was your mother I'd wash your mouth with soap to teach you being more polite ... but I'll accept the answer anyways, because I'm a nice guy, and because it's well detailed

Comment: @sebpiq: I've been very polite. That everybody here wasted the first three hours is not being rude, but a fact: we did not have the real testcase, so we could not even see the real problem, let alone solve it. You're welcome for the free help and my considerable time. Perhaps next time I'll bill you for those three hours at my typical rate.... :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8078/discussion-between-sebpiq-and-lightness-races-in-orbit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a case of the copy failing; it's a case of the copied array going out of scope before `console.log` *actually* outputs it, because `console.log` works asynchronously on some browsers (such as Chrome), and arrays are passed around by reference.

For example:

```
function foo() {
   var x = [];
   console.log(x);
   x = [1,2,3];
}

foo();
```

Under some conditions, [you'll see `[1,2,3]` output rather than the `[]` that you'd expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747421/javascript-console-prints-assigned-value-of-variable-before-it-has-been-assigned).

In your scenario, I'm not *entirely* sure what's going on, but I suspect `modelsBefore` has been re-used and emptied for the next invocation of code at that scope.

If you stringify early, though, you can get around it:

```
function foo() {
   var x = [];
   console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
   x = [1,2,3];
}

foo();
```

Stringification is a synchronous process, so you're guaranteed to see `[]` there.

Answer (score 3):

The first argument to `slice` [is *not* optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

> ```
> array.slice(begin[, end])
> ```

So:

```
this.models.slice(0);
```

Comment: @sebpiq: Time for a testcase that reproduces the issue. Also, just because using `slice` properly didn't fix your problem doesn't mean you should decide to use it improperly.

Comment: The word you're looking for is "problem"

Answer (score 1):

Slice requires start parameter

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle so we can test?

Comment: thing is ... I am using backbone.js, but I'll try.

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(this.models)) and use that in jsfiddle?

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/sebpiq/hYDbw/ ... I am guessing it's some kind of side effect because of backbone, but I don't even see how that could happen !!??

Comment: This jsfiddle still does not reveal how `this.models` is initialized/assigned and what prototype it has. Try to come up with a minimal test case, without any extraneous code. Can you reproduce this without Backbone? Try this as a last resort: `var modelsBefore = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.models, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

The Collection.models in Backbone is not an Array, it is an Object. Do not expect .slice() to work correctly with it. Look for another implementation that can do what you are expecting from .slice().