# Is this irregular behavior caused by Javascript running asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

```
  Snake.prototype.move = function() {
    var head = this.head();
    var newCoord = new Coord(head.pos);

    console.log(head, newCoord);
    console.log(head.pos, newCoord.pos);

    this.segments.push(newCoord);
    head.plus(this.dir);

    if (this.growingCount > 0) {
      this.growingCount -= 1;
    } else {
      this.segments.pop();
    }
  };
```

`Coord()` Constructor and `plus` function:

```
var Coord = SnakeGame.Coord = function(pos) {
    this.pos = pos;
  };

  Coord.prototype.plus = function(dir) {
    if (dir === "U") {
      this.pos[0] -= 1;
    } else if (dir === "D") {
      this.pos[0] += 1;
    } else if (dir === "R") {
      this.pos[1] += 1;
    } else if (dir === "L") {
      this.pos[1] -= 1;
    }
  };
```

`head()` returns the first segment in the `segments` property on the `Snake` instance.

The problem I'm seeing is that it seems like the two `console.log`'s are showing different results. The first line shows the `Coord` objects with a `pos` value of [3, 2] (which shouldn't be the case since `head` hasn't been updated yet). The next `console` line, outputs [3, 3] and [3, 3] (which should be the case).

What's going on? I feel like the error is staring at me in the face and I can't see it.

Clarification: Basically the `head` and `newCoord` when they're first instantiated, to have the same positions (unchanged). After the `head.plus(this.dir);` line, `head` should be one position further than `newCoord`.

One execution of the method should have `head.pos` be [3, 2] and `newCoord` to have [3, 3]. Next execution, `head.pos` should be [3, 1], another `newCoord` should be [3, 2]. Does this make sense?

Comment: There's nothing async in that code, unless the functions you're calling are somehow async.

Comment: So I'm checking this out through node instead of running it through the browser. Node shows them correctly, but, i don't get why the browser is showing [3, 2] as the values for `Coord` still.

Comment: can you post the Coord() constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`console.log` can be async. Take a look:

- [JavaScript console prints assigned value of variable before it has been assigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747421/javascript-console-prints-assigned-value-of-variable-before-it-has-been-assigned)
- [console.log() async or sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync)

So, in the line

```
console.log(head, newCoord);
```

You are passing a reference to `head`. At the time the reference is evaluated to print its position, the position has already been changed. In the other line, instead:

```
console.log(head.pos, newCoord.pos);
```

You are passing a reference to the object that is currently stored at `head.pos`. You can then assign another value to `head.pos`, but the process triggered by `console.log` (which can happen later than that) will still have the reference to the original object, so it will actually print the value of the position at the time the `console.log` time was made.

Comment: Right, that would explain it. Is there any reason why this occurs only in Chrome, as opposed to running the program through node?

Comment: @DennisShy as one of the answers in the links says, the behavior of `console.log` is not standardized. So there isn't any reason why this should be the same in Chrome and in node.

Comment: @DennisShy Chrome is really terrible in that regard; its implementation of the `console` function is completely hostile to developer needs. I like Chrome as a *user*, but for development I use Firefox and Firebug (not perfect either, but way less weird).