# Value from $rootScope is not loaded properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, rootscope, angularjs-rootscope

So I'm basically trying to get a property from my `$rootScope` when the page loads. I need this property so I can display the value in my form.

After testing this:

```
console.log("DEBUG $rootScope", $rootScope);
console.log("DEBUG $rootScope.localClient", $rootScope.localClient);
```

I've noticed that `$rootScope` contains a `localClient` property, but `$rootScope.localClient` is undefined. Why is this?

See console screen below.

[image]

Here is where I fill the localClient object

```
function setClient(client, tvaNumber) {
    if (tvaNumber) {
        if (angular.isUndefined($rootScope.localClient))
            $rootScope.localClient = {};

        $rootScope.localClient[tvaNumber] = client; 
    }
}
```

Comment: are you assigning `localClient` property from async call?

Comment: As far as I know, no. Just a regular sync call. I'll add the initiation of the localClient as well

Comment: are you logging `$rootScope` before it assigns `localClient` value?

Comment: how do you call `setClient ` method?

Comment: I'm afraid it could be doing that, but the console says that `$rootScope` actually has a localClient. Wouldn't that mean it's already assigned?

Comment: every `setClient` call is synchronically, no async calls are done here

Comment: See console will show the updated value, because it ultimately refer to the reference of the variable, [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8747421/2435473)

Comment: Okay, based on this, why could my value not be in the rootScope?

Comment: You can utilize `$sessionStorage` if `$rootScope` is not working for you? I can show you how if you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing it like this,

```
console.log("DEBUG $rootScope.localClient", $rootScope['localClient']);
```

Comment: Still undefined.

Comment: what would be the difference by this way?

Comment: @Jordec are you trying to print it inside a function? can you post the full code

Comment: @PankajParkar this bracket notation is safe as they can include any characters, including spaces.

Comment: @Sajeetharan I understand, but I don't see things that you're mentioning inside `localClient`

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure the attribute loaded before use it, because JavaScripte always pass a reference to an object. Or you can try console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($rootScope)) get the real value.

One example:
`var a = {}; console.log(a);a.test = '1';`
[image]

Comment: [JavaScript console prints assigned value of variable before it has been assigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8747421/2435473)

Comment: yes, but you still can see it in debug information. So, it is why you can see localClient in debug panel, but it is undefined if you try use it.