# Javascript code execution order strangeness

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a section of Javascript/Coffeescript that seems to be executing out of order.

```
console.log list
console.log list[card_number]
if list[card_number]
  console.log "MATCHES"
  new_card = list[card_number]
else
  console.log "NO MATCHES"
  new_card = create_new_card(card_number)

create_new_card: (card_number) ->
  new_card =
    card_number: card_number
  list[new_card.card_number] = new_card
  return new_card
```

Every time I run this, the first `console.log` shows a list of cards that includes the new_card, **Even if the card hasn't been created yet**. Then it ALWAYS hits the `else`, no matter how many times it is run.

If I attempt to run `list[<card_number>]` in the Javascript console after this code runs, I receive the proper object, but each time the code runs on it's own, the same event happens.

Comment: Have you inspected the javascript it outputs?  You're giving us (and yourself apparently) an unnecessary level of abstraction here...

Comment: Are you logging in google chrome?

Comment: Chrome has some [quirks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198912/bizarre-console-log-behaviour-in-chrome-developer-tools) on this subject indeed, but it should not influence the code flow (i.e. making the `else` branch get executed).

Comment: We are logging this in google chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In google chrome, if you want to log objects with the state they had at the time of logging, you need to log a clone object or just stringify it.

```
var a = [];
console.log(a);
a[0] = 3;
```

Will log `[3]` because it logs a live object, while this will log `[]`:

```
var a = [];
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a)));
a[0] = 3;
```

It is also a live object logging but it is a throwaway clone that was cloned at the point in time when `a` didn't have any items.

This is not related to the possible logical errors in your code that @CallumRogers pointed out.

Comment: @CallumRogers: That's because you gave Chrome time to log. When you do it in one go, i.e. `foo = []; console.log(foo); foo[0] = 1;`, you see `[1]`.

Comment: I realised my mistake, deleted the comment. For posterity: http://i.imgur.com/vSwEF.png

Comment: @CallumRogers the code needs to be run as a single script, not separate scripts as in your screenshot.

Comment: @Callum: There is a timing/async issue with `console.log`. Compare http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/XfxhM/ and http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/CufTA/ and you should see it.

Comment: @Esailija: might be this is because of updated chrome version,
now when i try your examples, both print '' and none of the case prints value '3'

`var a = [];
console.log('1st='+a);
a[0] = 3;

var a = [];
console.log('2nd='+JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a)));
a[0] = 3;
1st= 
2nd=
`

Answer (score 1):

Your `create_new_card` function is wrong - you call `new_card.number` instead of `new_card.card_number` which always results in `undefined` being added to the list resulting the behaviour that you have observed. The correct version is:

```
create_new_card: (card_number) ->
  new_card =
    card_number: card_number
  list[new_card.card_number] = new_card
  return new_card
```

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo. That part is correct in the code I'm using, and I corrected it in the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Chrome? `console.log` [does not execute immediately](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91303). Its a shame, but too bad for us.