# jQuery console this returns result before event happens

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

jQuery quick question about event handling.

Here's simple code

```
<div id="txt">change me!</div>


$('#txt').click(function () {
    console.log(this);
    $(this).text('changed!');

});
```

this outputs

```
<div id="txt">changed!</div>
```

in console. Though `console.log(this)` is executed before `text()` method, I get result of `text()` method is fired. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Console.log [fires late in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91303).  If you wanted to log an element at the time of the click, you could create a clone of the element and then log the clone per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9136505/3033053).

Also, this should be inside the `$(document).ready` function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txt').click(function () {
        var foo = $(this).text();
        console.log(this);            // Will have changed! because it's firing after everything else
        $(this).text('changed!');    
        console.log(foo);    
    });
});
```

**Console Output**

```
<div id="txt">changed!</div>
change me!
```

See [Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imoshtokill/64m5gx8k/1/)

Comment: I understand. I am OK with final HTML output. But my question is the order of method(function) execution. What I was expecting to see in the console is `<div id="txt">change me!</div>`, not `<div id="txt">changed!</div>`, because `console.log` is executed before jquery `text()` method.

Comment: I see now. Another stuff I did not know of. i'll be aware of that from next time.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are running in 'this' context. As a result what ever you changing in $(this) will get hoisted to top of the function. A simple example:

```
$('#txt').click(function () {
    console.log(this);
    var a = 10;
    var b = 20;
    var c = a+b;
    console.log(c);    
    $(this).text('changed!');
    $(this).attr('test','test');
});
```

will hoist at the top

```
$(this).text('changed!');
$(this).attr('test','test');
```

and the result will be

```
<div id="txt" test="test">changed!</div>
30
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oeaw9mLy/)

Comment: This doesn't make any sense at all.  Hoisting only hoists variable declarations (not definitions) and function expressions, it doesn't rearrange lines of code like you're suggesting.  `console.log(c);` will always fire before `$(this).text('changed');` in your example, regardless of hoisting.