# Console not behaving as expected when logged objects change

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

I'm not really sure if this is to do with JS or Chrome or console.log or what but would be interested to get an answer.

I am coding in Eclipse and running in Chrome using `console.log` to do some debugging. My code is enclosed in the JQuery `.ready()` method.

I define a simple array `var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];` then log the array and its first value which gives me (as I would expect) the output `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `1`.

I then update the first value using `arr[0] = 12;` and log the same the array and the first value again. My code now looks like this:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[0]);
arr[0] = 12;
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[0]);
```

And get the following output:

```
[12, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1
[12, 2, 3, 4, 5]
12
```

My question is, why do the first and third lines both log with the updated first value when the first log is called before that value is entered?

Is this just a lag with calling the log method or is there something else going on here?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It's the chrome console "lag"

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198912/bizarre-console-log-behaviour-in-chrome-developer-tools, and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays