# this.SOMETHING always returns undefined - extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, scope, extjs4

I have a portlet that includes a tabbed panel. In that panel is a chart. In one of the chart's functions, I do a `console.log(this)` and am able to view all of the contents.  However, my main intention is to use the value `this.ownerCt`, this says that it exists, but when I try to use it, or console.log it, it reports as undefined.  If I do a `this.id` or `this.idname` I get the actual ids.

Problem: Why would `this.SOMETHING` return `undefined` if there is a value for it in `this`?

Some code tidbits:
here is `console.log(this)`.

```
Ext.Class.newClass
  additionalCls: Array[2]
  body: Ext.Element.Ext.core.Element
  childEls: Array[1]
  collapseDirection: "top"
  componentCls: "x-panel"
  componentLayout: Ext.Class.newClass
  componentLayoutCounter: 3
  container: Ext.Element.Ext.core.Element
  dockedItems: Ext.Class.newClass
  el: Ext.Element.Ext.core.Element
  id: "stackedbarportlet-1055"
  itemId: "graph"
  items: Ext.Class.newClass
  ownerCt: Ext.Class.newClass
  xtype: "stackedbarportlet"
```

I took a few instances out, but this is the general output of it!

`console.log(this.ownerCt)` results in:   `undefined`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what `console.log(this)` prints, and the code where you reference `this.ownerCt`.

Comment: You are going need to provide example code, this is probably a scoping issue and the only way we can tell where is if you provide code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>

var t1="";
var t2;

if (t1===undefined)
{
alert("t1 is undefined");
}
if (t2===undefined)
{
alert("t2 is undefined");
}

</script>
```

if you run that t2 is undefined
probably **this.ownerCt** has no value

Comment: But if `this` shows that `this.ownerCt` does indeed have a value, then why does it still output as undefined?

Answer (score 0):

You may find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198912/bizarre-console-log-behaviour-in-chrome-developer-tools). It seems that sometimes `console.log()` invocations are queued and eventually invoked after the end of the current statement, so their output don't  necessarily reflect the object state exactly in the moment as it is in the code.

At least, I experienced similar behavior when I was overriding the constructor function in custom defined ExtJS's store.